# How do I add ContactPointAddress.PreferenceRank field?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, sandbox, migration

Hi I am comparing a sandbox to production and noticed that two additional fields are present on the Contact Point Address object in the sandbox.

- Preference Rank
- Usage Type

I don't think they are custom fields because they don't have __c and I can't find them to add to a change set.

Any idea where they come from...and how I can add them to my production envionment?

Its causing a lot of errors when I try to deploy my sandbox to production.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your sandbox on Winter'21 release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per release notes, ContactPointAddress object was introduced as part of [Summer'20 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_security_data_protection_privacy.htm) and two fields (PreferenceRank,UsageType) were added and are available in Winter'21 release orgs and you won't see this fields available in Summer'20 orgs.

Summer'20:

[image]
Winter'21:

[image]

Thanks,